# Where is a good place outside of the stackexchange network to ask a subjective question but still get the quality and maturity of the SE community?

Tags: discussion, subjective

I had a [subjective question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62916/why-is-there-so-much-hate-for-net-in-the-world) that I was pretty sure would get closed, and it did.  Before I wrote this question I debated with myself for quite a while before asking it for a few reasons.  I highly respect the Stack Exchange network and I didn't want to get my question closed for violating the standards and guidelines of questions.  I also wrote and re-wrote my question several times trying to get the wording right to follow the [six guidelines of subjective questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), which I failed.

Still things didn't seem right, so I decided to ask the meta site [where I should ask a subjective question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1333/where-do-i-ask-a-subjective-question).  Thank you to a [very helpful answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1333/where-do-i-ask-a-subjective-question/1334#1334) I was able to understand the reasons why my wording was poor and why my question was closed.  However, in my meta question I also asked

> "if there is not an appropriate stackexchange site, where is a good forum that I can ask that sort of question that has the maturity and popularity of the stackexchange sites so that I can get a quality response?"

Thank you to Jeff Atwood's comment, which I agree and kind of thought might be the case before I submitted the question in the first place, that the best place would have been to ask this outside of the stackexchange network.

So, my question is, where is a good place to go outside of the stackexchange network where I can ask this very subjective question (probably with better wording as suggested by the answers to my meta question) but still be reaching the maturity and quality of the stackexchange community?

Answer (score 4):

You're gonna have some trouble, since a key part of maintaining "the quality and maturity" of the SE network is built around *not* allowing questions like that...

But, you gotta start somewhere.  [Where can I find interesting programming discussions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13198/where-can-i-find-interesting-programming-discussions) has a few suggestions you might consider...

Also, I was recently informed that Prog.SE user [AmmoQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/6617/ammoq) has carved out a little corner on [The Daily WTF Forums](http://forums.thedailywtf.com/forums/27.aspx) specifically for questions that cannot and should not be asked here on Programmer's. TDWTF is not affiliated with Stack Exchange, and has its own standards of quality and conduct, so be respectful of these if you decide to make use of this resource.

Comment: Agreed, though I would qualify it that I still believe it's all in the wording - in other words "a key part of maintaining 'the quality and maturity' of the SE network is built around asking questions in a [professional, answerable manner](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)".  There is a version of that question I would vote to reopen.

Comment: @Renesis: there may be a form of that question that could exist here, but... It's a long way off. IMHO, key to being *answerable* involves not forcing answerers to guess at the motivations of anonymous, inarticulate critics... And unfortunately, that's sorta the *meat* of this question.

Comment: @Renesis I am working on trying to re-word my question in a manner that is suitable for SE, though when I read the guidlines for subjective questions and the link that you provided I find myself in a debate with myself if rewording it is "good enough" for SE.  I will give it a shot, but on the chance that I fail, or that even with the proper wording it doesn't get opened or attract the right answers I would like to move the "discussion" somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

You can try your luck here

http://forums.thedailywtf.com/forums/27.aspx

but I can't promise the maturity of p.se there.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that StackExchange discourages subjective questions.  In fact, the Stack Exchange network has welcomed subjective questions as long as they meet those six guidelines.

The problem with your question is it's biased.  I can tell what your opinion is based on the wording of the questions.  Good subjective questions give absolutely no hint of your opinion.

One way to make your subjective question less biased is to ask the question so that you target both the people who dislike the subject as well as those who like it?

`What are some of the reasons people dislike .NET and what are some of the reasons people like .NET?`

This question is less likely to be closed as `subjective and argumentative`.  Do I like .NET or dislike it?  Can you tell?  I hope you see my point, and I hope this helps you rework your question to where you can ask it here.  Good luck!